# Need help with Ubuntu 22 partitioning and install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04

I need to install Ubuntu 22 in legacy because of dual boot with win7.
I have checked with `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios` with the live cd and result is bios. However every time I try to install it says no uefi boot partition continue at own risk.
Should I continue? seeing I am in bios or will it make OS unbootable.

I have read some say to make a /boot partition, others say you don't need one. Do I need to make a 1Mb partition for bios boot at the beginning root partition?.
I have not been able to upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04 and have been stuck on 16.04 for this very same reason. Not sure what to do and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Albert

Comment: Your title mention Ubuntu 22 (*closest system being Ubuntu Core 22*) but NOTE Ubuntu products using the *year* release are different systems to those using the *year.month* format, ie. 22 is a different system to 22.04.  If you're after a replacement of Ubuntu 16.04 you should **not** install Ubuntu Core 22 (*which is still in beta; with release to occur in a week+*)   22 systems are *server* only ; where as 22.04 is available for *server* or *desktop* systems as is a more complete system.

Comment: This should be a good cue to finally retire Windows 7... It has been EOL for several years now. It has a huge library of critical vulnerabilities that will never be patched and it's a flashing red target for anyone looking to exploit your system. It's simply not responsible to continue using it if you connect the device to the internet. You can format your disk as GPT and install a modern system which will clear you from the restrictions that make dual booting difficult (MBR drives can only have 4 partitions)

Comment: FYI:  Whilst I'm unclear of what you're installing; assuming it's 22.04 (and not 22) there are ISOs that use `subiquity`, `ubiquity` & `calamares` (*flavors*) installers and the *warning* you mention can be ignored if you're using a legacy/BIOS system and it'll boot. The message is warning you it won't boot if you're using uEFI & an ESP (*EFI system partition*) is required.  This is *generic* advice as your details are *vague*

Comment: @Nmath Win7 does not connect to the internet, I only use it to print inkscape drawings that Ubuntu wont print correctly, but Win7 does

Comment: @guiverc I meant 22.04 that I downloaded from the Ubuntu site, I don't know about installer flavors. But I think you answered my question about ignoring the warning message. Not sure how to explain it in more detail.

Comment: Even if you don't want to or can't do that task on Ubuntu, you certainly don't need W7. You can use W10 or W11. I suggest you move on from this and stop justifying using W7 because there's no acceptable justification for it. If you want help with this you'll need to get past this because otherwise you will continue to be restricted by the MBR partitioning scheme.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 22.04 installed correctly like you said. Would you like to put your comment as an answer for me to tick.

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer; you can then accept it (*after the required wait time*) to gain some rep. for this site. You can credit/reference me if you wish... I've already written an detailed answer on this site about that topic, but can't find it currently  (it was Lubuntu/calamares but same ESP/EFI/boot-warning issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @guiverc for the comment answer above.

The warning about no uefi partition and continue at own risk is only for efi install. If you have to (or want to) use legacy, just be sure that live disc is booted into bois by checking with `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios` then continue. All worked as expected